# TFS Build using conditional compilation symbols (DefineConstants) from .csproj file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a solution that I build in TFS 2010 build. This solution and its build has 3 configurations set (Development, Integration, Release). I have set the build to build all of them, and it works mostly fine.

In this solution, there's a Silverlight project, which sets different conditional compilation symbols depending on which configuration is being built because it has different web service URLs for each configuration, like this:

```
    private const string STR_WS_EndPoint =
#if INTEGRATION
        "Integration_WS_EndPoint";
#elif DEVELOPMENT
        "Development_WS_EndPoint";
#elif DEBUG
        "Debug_WS_EndPoint";
#else
        "Release_WS_EndPoint";
#endif
```

When I build these different configurations in Visual Studio, it selects the right string for each configuration, but when TFS builds the different configuration, they all end up with the "Release_WS_EndPoint" string (I checked using ILSpy), i.e. none of the conditional symbols were active. How do I get TFS build to pick up on these compilation symbols? I can't use the "MSBuild Arguments" field in the build for this, because like I said, it builds all the different configurations, so I need it to use the .csproj compilation symbols like Visual Studio does.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [XmlPreprocess tool](http://xmlpreprocess.codeplex.com/) for config files manipulation depending on the build configuration. It is using one mapping file for multiple environments/servers. You can edit mapping file by Excel. It is very easy to use.
Call XmlPreprocess in the after build step and pass configuration as environment parameter.